# Problema css height 100%

Tags: html, css

Porque no me llega a ocupar toda la pantalla si tengo el `height` en el `body,html` y el contenido?

Paso el código:

```css
#secundario {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffff55;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#principal {
  margin-left: 210px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffffbb;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  height: 100%;
}

#contenido {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 100%;
}

#cabecera {
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  background-image: url("logocabecera.jpg");
}

#primeracolumna ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

#secundario h3 {
  color: #b4045f;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#principal img {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

#principal h3 {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b4045f;
}

.menuvertical2 {
  width: 170px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

.menuvertical2 li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.menuvertical2 li a:hover,
li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#pie {
  background: #338000;
  clear: both;
  height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.enlaces {
  float: left;
}

.enlaces a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.enlaces a:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.creador {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
  <div id="cabecera">
    <h1>LOGOTIPO</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="secundario">
    Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.<br/>
    <h3>Mis buscadores</h3>
    <div id="primeracolumna">
      <ul class="menuvertical">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><br/>
    <h3>Otras informaciones</h3>
    Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Los parques nacionales</h3><br/>
    <ul class="menuvertical2">
      <li><a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.picoseuropa.net/">PN Picos de Europa</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ordesapirineos.com/">PN de Ordesa y Monte perdido</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.monfrague.com/">PN de Monfrag&uuml;e</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.lleidatur.com/esp/parcnacional.html">PN de Aig&uuml;estortes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="principal">
    <h3>Informacion principal</h3>
    Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Sierra de Gredos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\gredos.jpg" title="Sierra de gredos" /> La sierra de Gredos es una sierra perteneciente al sistema Central, en la península ibérica, situada entre las provincias españolas de Salamanca, Cáceres,
      Ávila, Madrid y Toledo. Su máxima altitud se da en la provincia de Ávila en la Plaza del Moro Almanzor a 2592 msnm. Gredos es una de las sierras más extensas del sistema Central y en torno a sus grandes moles graníticas basculan cuatro comunidades
      autónomas: Castilla y León, Castilla-La Mancha, Extremadura y Madrid. Se extiende de este a oeste desde San Martín de Valdeiglesias a Hervás y de norte a sur del valle del Tormes a Rosarito. Parte de la sierra está declarada parque regional.</p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Pirineos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\pirineos.jpg" /> Los Pirineos, o el Pirineo como prefieren denominar sus habitantes al referirse a una parte o región de éstos (español: Pirineos; francés: Pyrénées; catalán: Pirineus; occitano:
      Pirenèus; aragonés: Pireneus/Perinés; euskera: Pirinioak o Auñamendiak), son una cordillera montañosa situada al norte de la península ibérica, entre España, Andorra y Francia. Se extiende a lo largo de 430 km desde el mar Mediterráneo (cabo de
      Creus) al este, hasta su unión con la cordillera Cantábrica al oeste, donde se ha establecido la falla de Pamplona como su límite convencional geológico, no existiendo interrupción geográfica entre ambas formaciones.1​ En su parte central tiene
      una anchura de unos 150 km. </p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Picos de Europa</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\picoseuropa.jpg" /> Los Picos de Europa son un macizo montañoso localizado en el norte de España que pertenece a la parte central de la cordillera Cantábrica. Aunque no muy extenso, su cercanía
      al mar hace que sea pródigo en accidentes geográficos de gran interés. En la actualidad el Parque nacional de los Picos de Europa constituye el segundo parque nacional más visitado de España, después del Parque nacional del Teide (Tenerife).</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pie">
    <span class="enlaces">
         <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a> |
         <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> | 
         <a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a> |
         <a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a> |
         <a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a>
        </span>
    <span class="creador">V&iacute;ctor Funcia Tom&eacute;.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

En mi otro ordenador que tiene una resolución de `1920x1080` se ve perfectamente. Sin embargo en el otro que tiene una resolución de `1366x768` se ve cortado el fondo amarillo de la etiqueta `principal` y `secundaria` como aparece en la imagen justo al empezar el `h3` de los picos de europa y no se porque ocurre esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes detallar mas concretamente que te falla?

Comment: Creo que es el height 100% ya que en mi otro ordenador que tiene una resolución de 1920x1080 se ve perfectamente. Sin embargo en el otro que tiene una resolución de 1366x768 se ve cortado el fondo amarillo de la etiqueta principal y secundaria como aparece en la imagen justo al empezar el  h3 de los picos de europa y no se porque ocurre esto.

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta con el div secundario, que es el que te esta limitando el alto. Prueba a cambiar el height: 100%; por height: auto;

Answer (score 2):

El porcentaje sobre un `height` se aplica sobre el número de píxeles del elemento padre, que en tu caso no tienes asignado en ningúna parte de los estilos. Puedes probar a darle un `height` especifico al elemento padre, o darle un `height: auto` a los contenedores para que se ajusten a la altura de los elementos que contienen.

Podría ser algo así;

```css
#secundario {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffff55;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

#principal {
  margin-left: 210px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffffbb;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  height: auto;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  height: 100%;
}

#contenido {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 100%;
}

#cabecera {
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  background-image: url("logocabecera.jpg");
}

#primeracolumna ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

#secundario h3 {
  color: #b4045f;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#principal img {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

#principal h3 {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b4045f;
}

.menuvertical2 {
  width: 170px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

.menuvertical2 li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.menuvertical2 li a:hover,
li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#pie {
  background: #338000;
  clear: both;
  height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.enlaces {
  float: left;
}

.enlaces a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.enlaces a:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.creador {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
  <div id="cabecera">
    <h1>LOGOTIPO</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="secundario">
    Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.<br/>
    <h3>Mis buscadores</h3>
    <div id="primeracolumna">
      <ul class="menuvertical">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><br/>
    <h3>Otras informaciones</h3>
    Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Los parques nacionales</h3><br/>
    <ul class="menuvertical2">
      <li><a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.picoseuropa.net/">PN Picos de Europa</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ordesapirineos.com/">PN de Ordesa y Monte perdido</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.monfrague.com/">PN de Monfrag&uuml;e</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.lleidatur.com/esp/parcnacional.html">PN de Aig&uuml;estortes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="principal">
    <h3>Informacion principal</h3>
    Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Sierra de Gredos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\gredos.jpg" title="Sierra de gredos" /> La sierra de Gredos es una sierra perteneciente al sistema Central, en la península ibérica, situada entre las provincias españolas de Salamanca, Cáceres,
      Ávila, Madrid y Toledo. Su máxima altitud se da en la provincia de Ávila en la Plaza del Moro Almanzor a 2592 msnm. Gredos es una de las sierras más extensas del sistema Central y en torno a sus grandes moles graníticas basculan cuatro comunidades
      autónomas: Castilla y León, Castilla-La Mancha, Extremadura y Madrid. Se extiende de este a oeste desde San Martín de Valdeiglesias a Hervás y de norte a sur del valle del Tormes a Rosarito. Parte de la sierra está declarada parque regional.</p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Pirineos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\pirineos.jpg" /> Los Pirineos, o el Pirineo como prefieren denominar sus habitantes al referirse a una parte o región de éstos (español: Pirineos; francés: Pyrénées; catalán: Pirineus; occitano:
      Pirenèus; aragonés: Pireneus/Perinés; euskera: Pirinioak o Auñamendiak), son una cordillera montañosa situada al norte de la península ibérica, entre España, Andorra y Francia. Se extiende a lo largo de 430 km desde el mar Mediterráneo (cabo de
      Creus) al este, hasta su unión con la cordillera Cantábrica al oeste, donde se ha establecido la falla de Pamplona como su límite convencional geológico, no existiendo interrupción geográfica entre ambas formaciones.1​ En su parte central tiene
      una anchura de unos 150 km. </p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Picos de Europa</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\picoseuropa.jpg" /> Los Picos de Europa son un macizo montañoso localizado en el norte de España que pertenece a la parte central de la cordillera Cantábrica. Aunque no muy extenso, su cercanía
      al mar hace que sea pródigo en accidentes geográficos de gran interés. En la actualidad el Parque nacional de los Picos de Europa constituye el segundo parque nacional más visitado de España, después del Parque nacional del Teide (Tenerife).</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pie">
    <span class="enlaces">
         <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a> |
         <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> | 
         <a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a> |
         <a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a> |
         <a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a>
        </span>
    <span class="creador">V&iacute;ctor Funcia Tom&eacute;.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, lo puedes poner en el body o en cualquier sección que necesites ver a pantalla completa

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo es darle al body el tamaño de la pantalla, por lo que si la página mide más de lo que mide la pantalla el 100% no ocupa todo lo que quieres que ocupe.

Una solución que igual no es la mejor es darle un tamaño fijo al body, en tu caso :

```
html,
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
  height: 1018px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que en el monitor de mayor resolución el contenido de la página entra sin necesidad de hacer `scroll`.

Creo que una mejor solución a tu problema es utilizar [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS)

Así por ejemplo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
}

#contenido {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 750px;
  
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#contenido > * {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

#cabecera {
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  background-image: url("logocabecera.jpg");
}
#secundario {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffff55;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
}

#principal {
  flex: 1 0;
  
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ffffbb;
  border: 1px solid #555555;
}

#primeracolumna ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 130px;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

#secundario h3 {
  color: #b4045f;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

#primeracolumna ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#principal img {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

#principal h3 {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b4045f;
}

.menuvertical2 {
  width: 170px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #7c7c7c;
}

.menuvertical2 li a {
  padding: .2em 0 .2em 1.5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333000;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.menuvertical2 li a:hover,
li a:active {
  background: #58fa58;
}

#pie {
  background: #338000;
  clear: both;
  height: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.enlaces {
  float: left;
}

.enlaces a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.enlaces a:hover {
  background: #336699;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.creador {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido">
  <div id="cabecera">
    <h1>LOGOTIPO</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="secundario">
    Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.Columna a la izquierda.<br/>
    <h3>Mis buscadores</h3>
    <div id="primeracolumna">
      <ul class="menuvertical">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><br/>
    <h3>Otras informaciones</h3>
    Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.Otras informaciones.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Los parques nacionales</h3><br/>
    <ul class="menuvertical2">
      <li><a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.picoseuropa.net/">PN Picos de Europa</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.ordesapirineos.com/">PN de Ordesa y Monte perdido</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.monfrague.com/">PN de Monfrag&uuml;e</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.lleidatur.com/esp/parcnacional.html">PN de Aig&uuml;estortes</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="principal">
    <h3>Informacion principal</h3>
    Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.Contenido principal.
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Sierra de Gredos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\gredos.jpg" title="Sierra de gredos" /> La sierra de Gredos es una sierra perteneciente al sistema Central, en la península ibérica, situada entre las provincias españolas de Salamanca, Cáceres,
      Ávila, Madrid y Toledo. Su máxima altitud se da en la provincia de Ávila en la Plaza del Moro Almanzor a 2592 msnm. Gredos es una de las sierras más extensas del sistema Central y en torno a sus grandes moles graníticas basculan cuatro comunidades
      autónomas: Castilla y León, Castilla-La Mancha, Extremadura y Madrid. Se extiende de este a oeste desde San Martín de Valdeiglesias a Hervás y de norte a sur del valle del Tormes a Rosarito. Parte de la sierra está declarada parque regional.</p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Pirineos</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\pirineos.jpg" /> Los Pirineos, o el Pirineo como prefieren denominar sus habitantes al referirse a una parte o región de éstos (español: Pirineos; francés: Pyrénées; catalán: Pirineus; occitano:
      Pirenèus; aragonés: Pireneus/Perinés; euskera: Pirinioak o Auñamendiak), son una cordillera montañosa situada al norte de la península ibérica, entre España, Andorra y Francia. Se extiende a lo largo de 430 km desde el mar Mediterráneo (cabo de
      Creus) al este, hasta su unión con la cordillera Cantábrica al oeste, donde se ha establecido la falla de Pamplona como su límite convencional geológico, no existiendo interrupción geográfica entre ambas formaciones.1​ En su parte central tiene
      una anchura de unos 150 km. </p>
    <br/><br/>
    <h3>Picos de Europa</h3>
    <br/>
    <p><img src="RecursosUnidad2\Imagenes y Textos Actividades\picoseuropa.jpg" /> Los Picos de Europa son un macizo montañoso localizado en el norte de España que pertenece a la parte central de la cordillera Cantábrica. Aunque no muy extenso, su cercanía
      al mar hace que sea pródigo en accidentes geográficos de gran interés. En la actualidad el Parque nacional de los Picos de Europa constituye el segundo parque nacional más visitado de España, después del Parque nacional del Teide (Tenerife).</p>
  </div>
  <div id="pie">
    <span class="enlaces">
         <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a> |
         <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a> | 
         <a href="http://www.msn.com/">Msn</a> |
         <a href="http://www.altavista.com/">Altavista</a> |
         <a href="http://reddeparquesnacionales.mma.es/parques/index.htm">Red de PP.NN.</a>
        </span>
    <span class="creador">V&iacute;ctor Funcia Tom&eacute;.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```